# Remove "Billing state" and "Shipping state" for Woocommerce E-mail templates

Tags: php, wordpress, email, templates, woocommerce

Anyone know how I could hide this? I tried unhooking, but whatever I write down in the php... It just stops working:
/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-addresses.php

I would like to remove the "Billing and Shipping State field info" from the mail that is sent to the customer.

[image]

Comment: which hooks/filters have you tried? do you have code to share?

Comment: This question may be better suited for SO's sister site StackExchange that's dedicated to WordPress. I believe it's https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `woocommerce_order_get_formatted_shipping_address` filter?
[Here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/55fd39d49316acda5ea0389ad0df702e143e3449/includes/class-wc-order.php#L917) you can see how it's work.